# Blind SQL Injection vulnerability?

Tags: commerce, 9

What is the purpose of this unique ID appended to this class in Drupal 9 HTML?

```
js-view-dom-id-7881eb5bafcd4178e6af77ed45179be612e74557a6807989024fac282b24f164
```

I'm getting what I believe are false positives for Blind SQL Injection from a PCI scan and the only thing I can see different in there tests are these types of things throughout the page. I think I know part of the purpose, but am looking for more information to submit with a false positive report.

EDIT: The URL parameter being tested is our product page with the variation parameter (v) ...

```
?v=65%22listsrc'%20or%203789%3D3789%20--%20

?v=65%22listsrc'%20and%203789%3D3789%20--%20
```

If I run queries on the db like ...

```
SELECT * FROM pantheon.commerce_product__variations
WHERE variations_target_id = '65"listsrc' or 3789=3789 -- '

SELECT * FROM pantheon.commerce_product__variations
WHERE variations_target_id = '65"listsrc' and 3789=3789 -- '
```

The one with the "or" returns all variations while the one with the "and" returns just the correct one.

Is this significant? The page loaded still only shows the correct variation.

Thanks!

Comment: Long ago it was named `view-dom-id-`. `git log -S'view-dom-id-` shows this has been in the core codebase for a very long time.